# how to run this vbscript

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have got two files 'uninstall.vbs' and 'uninstall.bat'. The uninstall.vbs script calls uninstall.bat which does the uninstallation. Both these files are present inside the same directory 'C:\Program Files\MyApp\v1.1'

I want to execute the vbscript in the following way

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wscript "C:\Program Files\MyApp\v1.1\uninstall.vbs"
```

When I try to execute it gives me the following error

[image: Error]

Here is my uninstall.vbs script

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "uninstall.bat", 0, True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the current directory of the shell object.

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Shell.CurrentDirectory = Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "")
Shell.Run "uninstall.bat", 0, True
```

Also see this [Scripting Guy article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/08/23/can-i-change-the-current-directory-when-running-a-script.aspx).

Comment: @Tomalek - will upvote as soon as you use the FSO's ".GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)".

Comment: Uh, thanks, but I really don't see why that would be necessary. Replace should get the job done well enough for a three-liner like this one.

Answer (score 2):

The WScript.Shell won't find "uninstall.bat" if the isn't in the shell's current directory (or the PATH).

The low cost remedy is to specify the full path (quoted!):

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """C:\Program Files\MyApp\v1.1\uninstall.bat""", 0, True
```

See @Tomalek's answer, if your .vbs or .bat has **further** dependencies on the current directory.